# Minimum number of trials to get >99% chance of getting the median

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

### Context:

An algorithm is given (below); input array *A* is made of *n* elements, which are all odd, positive integers.

### Algorithm:

```
Median(A[1, ... , *n*])
1. Uniformly at random pick i ∈ {1, ... , *n*}.
2. c ← 0
3. foreach j ∈ {1, ... , *n*} 
4.     if A[j] < A[i] then c ← c+1
```

Note: the "if" statement (line 4) is supposed to be nested under the "foreach" statement (line 3).

```
5. if c = (n-1)/2 then return A[i]
6. else goto line 1
```

### Question:

Assume each execution of line 1 is defined to be a "trial". How many trials are needed to have atleast a 99% chance of returning successfully with the median value as shown in line 5? The answer will have a lower bound, and it will be a function of $n$.

### Thoughts:

Let $m$ be the number of trials, and $n$ be the possible values we're looking through. I realised that $\frac{m}{n} = \frac{trials}{elements} = $ the probability of finding the median. Assuming this is right, I go on to deduce that $\frac{m}{n} \geq 0.99$ because we need a probability of atleast 99%. Given this logic, I end up with $m \geq 0.99n$ but when trying to figure out the lower boundary I am getting confused as my approach doesn't seem to lead to a lower boundary.

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, so any help or hints on helping me understand any mistakes I'm making would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose $n$ is odd. (Not the elements in the list $A$.) The "median element" is colored in red, all others are black.

The probability to **not** extract the red number from the list in one step is 
$$
p = 1-\frac 1n\ .
$$
Let $K>0$ be a natural number.

The probability to **not** extract the red number from the list in $K$  steps is 
$$
p^K = \left(1-\frac 1n\right)^K\ .
$$
For a rather big $n$ we have 
$$
\left(1-\frac 1n\right)^n\approx \frac 1e=\exp(-1)\ .
$$
To get a value $p^K$ under $0.01=\frac 1{100}$, we need to repeat the experiment roughly some $K=n\log 100 =2n\log 10$ times. (So we repeat for instance $K=5n$ times the random extraction, $\log 100$ is numerically `4.60517018598809...` .)

For a given $n$ the value of $K$ can be computed explicitly.

Comment: For a large 'n' why does p^K have an exponent of n as opposed to K?

Comment: Or is it that we're saying we will need n trials when we have a big n? If so, why is that?

Comment: K was a variable, an unknown used in between to have a light notation. We are searching for a "good K" depending on n. It turns out that a good value for K that *approximatively* works for bigger values of n is like $K=(4.605\dots)n$. To have a clear situation, please declare an explicit value of $n$. Then we can also use Monte-Carlo to get numbers and the statistic. (I would use `sage` to ilustrate the situation experimentally.)